# lightning and multiple server-side constructors

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an Apex class with two constructors. When I call an @AuraEnabled method from the helper, it does not hit any of the constructors. How can I specify a constructor from the helper?

Thanks

Comment: `@AuraEnabled` method has nothing to do with constructors as they operate in static context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex server-side controllers for Lightning components use methods that are declared `static` and `@AuraEnabled`. Since `static` methods are not bound to an object instance, the constructor is never called during a server call from Lightning.

`static` methods don't get to maintain state between calls in instance variables. All of your state should be kept client-side, in your JavaScript controller or component attributes. Any initialization that must be done server-side has to be done in a `static` context, not in a constructor, unless the constructor is for some object that is itself instantiated within the `static` method.

Here's an example.

```
public class SampleController {
    private String myInstanceVar;
    public SampleController() {
        myInstanceVar = 'Test';
    }

    @AuraEnabled static void lightningControllerMethod() {
        // Here, `SampleController()` is never called
        // We can't access `myInstanceVar` in static context.
        String myLocalInstanceVar = 'Test'; // this is fine.
    }

    @AuraEnabled static void anotherLightningControllerMethod() {
        myCustomObject q = new MyCustomObject('Test');
        // myCustomObject() constructor *is* called, because we instantiated it here.
        // We still can't access `myInstanceVar`.
    }
}
```